# Neglecting higher order terms in a Lagrangian

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion, physics

I have a lagrangian which is modified by variable change. I want to neglect all the 4th order and higher terms in the new lagrangian. The code being used is given below:

```
lagrangian = 
  Sum[c[n]'[t]^2 - c[n][t]^2 ωsq[n], {n, {0, 1}}] + 
   11.3 c[0][t]^3 + 21.5 c[0][t] c[1][t]^2 + 
   10.7 c[0][t] c[0]'[t]^2 + 3.32 c[0][t] c[1]'[t]^2 + 
   6.64 c[0]'[t] c[1][t] c[1]'[t];

c[0][t_] := C[0][t] + α1 C[0][t]^2 + α2 C[1][t]^2;

c[1][t_] := C[1][t] + α3 C[0][t] C[1][t];

α1 = -1.5; α2 = -0.5; α3 = -1;

n = Expand[lagrangian]
```

I tried using this code to neglect the higher-order terms:

```
vars = {C[0][t], C[1][t]};
Normal[Series[n /. Thread[vars -> m*vars], {m, 0, 3}]] /. m -> 1
```

which does part of the job but there are still some higher-order derivative terms present. How to go about removing them too from the modified lagrangian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you just have to include the derivatives in the `vars`

```
vars = {C[0][t], C[1][t], C[0]'[t], C[1]'[t]};
Normal[Series[n /. Thread[vars -> m*vars], {m, 0, 3}]] /. m -> 1
```

> [image: higher]

Comment: Thank you for rectifying my error !

Comment: @codebpr you are most welcome. Thanks for the accept :)

Answer (score 6):

Another approach to insert the "smallness" parameter is:

```
Normal[
    Series[n /. C[i_] :> Function[m C[i][#]], {m, 0, 3}]
] /. m->1
```

> -ωsq[0] C[0][t]^2 + 11.3 C[0][t]^3 + 3. ωsq[0] C[0][t]^3 - ωsq[1] C[1][t]^2 +
> 21.5 C[0][t] C[1][t]^2 + 1. ωsq[0] C[0][t] C[1][t]^2 +
> 2 ωsq[1] C[0][t] C[1][t]^2 + C[0]'[t]^2 +
> 4.7 C[0][t] C[0]'[t]^2 +
> 2.64 C[1][t] C[0]'[t] C[1]'[t] +
> C[1]'[t]^2 + 1.32 C[0][t] C[1]'[t]^2

Comment: Heh, I thought of trying something like that but I couldn't get the syntax to work.  Thanks for figuring it out & posting it.

Comment: That's the most resilient approach. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this is to "tag" the expressions in the original code with some formal parameter $\epsilon$:

```
    c[0][t_] := ϵ C[0][t] + ϵ^2 α1 C[0][t]^2 + ϵ^2 α2 C[1][t]^2;

    c[1][t_] := ϵ C[1][t] + ϵ^2 α3 C[0][t] C[1][t];

    α1 = -1.5; α2 = -0.5; α3 = -1;

    newlagrangian = 
      Sum[c[n]'[t]^2 - c[n][t]^2 ωsq[n], {n, {0, 1}}] + 
       11.3 c[0][t]^3 + 21.5 c[0][t] c[1][t]^2 + 
       10.7 c[0][t] c[0]'[t]^2 + 3.32 c[0][t] c[1]'[t]^2 + 
       6.64 c[0]'[t] c[1][t] c[1]'[t];

    newn = Expand[newlagrangian]
```

You can then take the coefficients order by order in $\epsilon$, either using `Normal` and `Series` or by using `CoefficientList`:

```
    result = Total[Take[CoefficientList[newn, ϵ], 4]]
```

The `4` in there is because you want to keep the first four terms of the coefficient list, which correspond to terms of order $\epsilon^0$, $\epsilon^1$, $\epsilon^2$, and $\epsilon^3$.